# Override alertView method

Tags: ios, overriding, uialertview

I have a cell with a button. This button is used to delete the cell, when I touch the button I show an alertView before deletion. What I want is to pass the cell in parameter to the method such as below :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex forCell:(MissionCollectionViewCell *) cell
```

But I don't know how to do that during the initialisation of my UIAlertView ?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette mission ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Supprimer" otherButtonTitles:@"Annuler", nil];
```

Comment: you can store the current `NSIndexPath` in your class when you open the `UIAlertView`, and you can use that as reference later when you need to do a destructive procedure in the `– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method which called back – what you intended to do originally with the delegate and protocol is kinda impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to support iOS8+ you should move to using UIAlertController, which gives you block based handlers for actions and thus easy access to variables. If like many of us you need to cater for those not upgrading instantly, I have found the approach described [here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/04/ios-programming-recipe-22-simplify-uialertview-with-blocks/) to be the best way of dealing with UIAlertView.

The example at that link adds a category to UIAlertView to allow you to deal with the alert view completion using a block rather than a delegate. Using your example it would let you raise the alert and give you access in the completion to any variables you require:

```
UIAlertView *alert = 
  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention" 
                             message:@"Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette mission ?" 
                            delegate:self 
                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Supprimer" otherButtonTitles:@"Annuler", nil];

[alert showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    // Since this is a block defined where you called it you can use
    // the variables you want directly 8^).
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex){
      ... Code can access cell directly.
    }
}];
```

I now use this all the time since it is much simpler having your completion code next to where you raised the alert view.